# Why cannot use a1.print() on the main function to print the number of s

Tags: c++

This is the code we were taught, but I have a question. Why does the compiler give an error when using `a1.print()` in the `main()` function, but not when using `->`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A {
 protected:
  int _s;

 public:
  A(int s) : _s(s) {}
  A() : A(-1) {}

  void print() { cout << "s = " << this->_s << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
 private:
  double _k;

 public:
  B(int s, double k) {
    _k = k;
    _s = s;
  }
  B() : B(0, 0) {}
  void print() {
    // using protected can use this->s, cannot work on private
    cout << "s = " << this->_s << "k = " << this->_k << endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  A* a1;
  B b1(500, 0.258);
  // a pointer to a base class can point at an object from a derived class
  a1 = &b1;
  a1->print();  // cannot use a1.print() here,

  return 0;
}
```

Before the professor taught the code for us, we always use:

```
B b1(500,0.24);
b1.print();
```

But why is the professor using a pointer here?

Comment: Well, it seems to me if you are wondering why the professor used the pointer here, perhaps you should ask the professor?

Comment: Is this the same code the professor showed you?  I'd expect `virtual` with an example like this.

Comment: _"Why does the compiler give an error when using `a1.print()` in the main function, but not when using `->`."_ Because `a1` is a pointer. That's the syntax for pointers. _"But why professor use the pointer here?"_ Because he wants to teach you about pointers.

Comment: @StephenNewell I'm reading the question as "why is it `a1->print()` instead of `a1.print()`, to which the answer, Xu, is that a pointer needs to be dereferenced `*` before you can access its members. The `->` is just a shorthand way of writing *a1.print()

Comment: @fireshadow52 . I try to use *a1.print() here,but it is false to. May you told me how to use *a1.print() here

Comment: It's `(*a1).print();`. `.` has higher precedence than `*`. [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: @jabaa True. Thanks for that correction.

Comment: @fireshadow52 - This code smells like an attempt to get dynamic binding, hence calling `print` through an `A*`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the compiler give an error when using a1.print() in the main function, but not when using ->.

Because `->` is a **member access operator** whose left hand operand must be an expression of pointer to complete class type, `T*`. From [member access operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access):

> The member access operator expressions have the form
>
> - `expr . template(optional) id-expr`     (1)
> - `expr -> template(optional) id-expr`    (2)
>
> 1. The first operand must be an expression of complete class type T
> 2. The **first operand must be an expression of pointer to complete class type `T*`.**

(end quote)

This means that the left hand operand of `->` should be a *pointer to a complete class type*. In your example, the expression as the left hand operand(`a1`) is of type `A*` where `A` is a complete class type and thus condition 2 quoted above is satisfied and this works.

But if you were to use `a1.print();` then the left hand operand `a1` is of type `A*` which doesn't satisfy the condition 1 quoted above and so this fails.

---

> But why professor use the pointer here?

Only the professor can tell this for sure. We can only speculate why the professor choose to use the pointer here. One reason might be that he/she wants to teach you about pointers and **dynamic binding** in which case it would make more sense if he/she would've used `virtual` in for the member function `print`.